# Are there relation between $\mathbb{E}[ \det(A)]$ and $\det(\mathbb{E}[A])$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. 
Is there a relationship between $\mathbb{E}[\det(A)]$ and $\det(\mathbb{E}[A])$?

For example, for trace we have an equality relationship
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbb{E}[A])=\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Tr}(A)]
\end{align}

Comment: determinant will involve products, unless all elements are mutually independent you can't claim equality.  Trace is just the sum, where expectation can be distributed.

Comment: @karakfa Sure. That is why I asked if there is a relationship and not an equality.  For example, can we show if one quantity is larger than the other.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: @ClementC.  Thank you. For letting me know how to do this. I will keep this in mind in the future. I usually don't check my account over the weekend.

Comment: @Boby No worries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple counter example, 
let $A = \begin{pmatrix}x&0\\0&y\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbb{E}\{\det A\}=E\{xy\}$  whereas, $\det \mathbb{E}\{A\}=E\{x\}E\{y\}$ Unless $x$ and $y$ are independent you can't claim any relationships.

Answer (score 4):

**No.** For the trace, you can use linearity of expectation. For the determinant, you have products, and unless you have strong independence assumptions between the entries of your random matrices, anything can happen.

- Take $A$ to be $0_n$ with probability $1/2$, and $4I_n$ with probability $1/2$.

  Then $\mathbb{E}[\det A] = \frac{1}{2}\left( 0+4^n\right) = 4^{n-1}$, but
  $\det \mathbb{E}[A] = \left(\frac{0+4}{2}\right)^n = 2^n$. In this case,
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[\det A] > \det \mathbb{E}[A] \tag{1}
  $$
- Take $A$ to be $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ with probability $1/2$, and $\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ with probability $1/2$.

  Then $\mathbb{E}[\det A] = \frac{1}{2}\left( 0+0\right) = 0$, but
  $\det \mathbb{E}[A] = \det\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=1$. In this case,
  $$
  \mathbb{E}[\det A] < \det \mathbb{E}[A] \tag{2}
  $$

Comment: Great. Thank you.    If we assume that $E[A]$ is positive definite can we say more?

Comment: No. It already is for both examples.